# Positive Semidefinite Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

Let $x=\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
x_{1} & x_{2} & \cdots  & x_{n}%
\end{array}%
\right] $ be a vector with $\sum x_{i}=1$ and $x_{i}>0$. Is there an easy way
to prove that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{diag}\left\{ x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}\right\} -xx^{T}
\end{equation}
is positive semi-definite and has one zero eigenvalue with algebraic
dimension one.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the definition of semi-positive ($v^*Av\geq0$), the fact that *all* $x_i\in[0,1]$ (you need both bounds!) and Young's inequality ($2ab<a^2+b^2$)
for $n$ terms. A 0-eigenvector (which is a slick way to say solution to the homogeneous system) is perhaps written in front of you?